# Regulation for ETFs in the UK after the Brexit

Tags: investing, regulation, brexit

Currently the UK is in the EU, that means that the financial products sold in the UK are under the EU regulation (UCITS).

After the UK leaves the EU, this regulation will no longer be applicable. Will this impact to individual investors? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's about an EU directive. The way EU directives work is that each member state is obligated to make laws that comply with it. But these aren't EU laws. They are laws of each individual country. They can and will be different from country to country but they need to comply with the general idea. Leaving the EU won't make UK laws go away.

Comment: Although, for completeness, if the UK _does_ leave, it would then not be under an obligation to _keep_ the current law(s). That doesn't mean the situation _will_ change, only that it _could_ change.